# Return Func from Func

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to dynamically generate linqtosql query using [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). I would like to check the field that I want to add for the prediction before sending the expression to LinqKit.  So I have come up with some idea like

```
 Expression<Func<TResult, bool>> GetPrediction<TKey>
                            (Expression<Func<TResult, TKey>> selector, TResult input,  object value)
 {
    if(typeof(TKey) == typeof(string))
    {
         return selector.Invoke(input) == value; //Not working, how to covert here?
    }
    Throw new Exception("Type not supported");
 }
```

I am stuck at line 5, where I am supposed to generate an Expression`<Func<TResult, bool>>` and return. I know it's possible but just have hard time to get the "click"

Comment: What error are you getting? from your code here i can see you are trying to return a bool while your method expects an Expression<Func<TResult, bool>> ...

Comment: I know why it's not working. That line is there as a place holder. What I really want to return is an Expression, but am having hard time to find how.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do .. maybe if you explain the original problem i might be able to help .. as it is right now .. i'm lost.

Comment: Sorry about losing you. The original problem is about using LinqKit with customized behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
public static Expression<Func<TResult, bool>> GetPredicate<TKey>
    (Expression<Func<TResult, TKey>> selector, TResult input, object value)
{
    // Note: Move "early out" here so that bulk of method is less deeply nested.
    // Really? Why make this generic in TKey then?
    if (typeof(TKey) != typeof(string))
    {
        throw new Exception("Type not supported");
    }

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter("input");
    var invocation = Expression.Invoke(selector, input);
    var constant = Expression.Constant(value);
    var equality = Expression.Equal(invocation, constant);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TResult, bool>>(equality, parameter);
}
```

I'm not quite sure what kind of equality that will use, mind you - it's entirely possible it's going to use a *reference* equality operation, whereas I suspect you want *value* equality. You'll have to try it to see, being careful in tests due to string interning.

Comment: Thanks a lot! the early out part is actually not only for string. The reason I want to limit the types is because LinqToSql will throw "Cannot translate to SQL" exception if my predicate contains customized type. So, I want to have only primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

```
return p => (selector.Compile().Invoke(input) as string) == value
```